# Excessive computation time for ParametricPlot

Tags: graphics

How can I improve the excessive computation time for this plot. (Warning: do not attempt)

```
ParametricPlot[{{Integrate[Cos[Integrate[u - 1, {u, 0, m}]], {m, 0, s}], Integrate[Sin[Integrate[u - 1, {u, 0, m}]], {m, 0, s}]}, {-Integrate[Cos[Integrate[u - 1, {u, 0, m}]], {m, 0, s}], Integrate[Sin[Integrate[u - 1, {u, 0, m}]], {m, 0, s}]}}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 15]
```

[image]

Comment: Include the option `Evaluated -> True`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this particular case, pre-computing the integrals in terms of `s` helps immensely, since the results are expressible in terms of Fresnel integrals:

```
curves[s_] = {{Integrate[Cos[Integrate[u - 1, {u, 0, m}]], {m, 0, s}],
               Integrate[Sin[Integrate[u - 1, {u, 0, m}]], {m, 0, s}]}, 
              {-Integrate[Cos[Integrate[u - 1, {u, 0, m}]], {m, 0, s}], 
               Integrate[Sin[Integrate[u - 1, {u, 0, m}]], {m, 0, s}]}}

(* Output: somewhat complicated expression involving FresnelS and FresnelC *)

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[curves[s]], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 15]

(* Output:  same plot as in question, with less than 1 second of computer time *)
```